# Validation of draft-js EditorState via yup in Formik

Tags: draftjs, formik, yup

I'm using [Draft-js with Formik](https://codesandbox.io/s/QW1rqjBLl) with **yup** for validation of the Draft EditorState component.

I assumed I would be able to check that EditorState is not blank by using the following yup test:

```
//Each note has a string title and a body, which is a Draft EditorState
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup.string(),
  body: yup.object()
    .test("has text", "Cannot save an empty note", (value) => {
      return value.getCurrentContent().hasText();  //boolean
  }),
})
```

However, I get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at yupToFormErrors (formik.esm.js:491) at formik.esm.js:174

Is this a bug with **formik**, or am I using **yup** incorrectly?

**Other information:**

Inside validationSchema, I get the following:

```
console.log(value.getCurrentContent().hasText())  //returns undefined
console.log(value.getCurrentContent())  //returns undefined
```

But inside an onChange handler for EditorState ('body' field) it works properly:

```
console.log(value.getCurrentContent().hasText())  //returns true or false
```

Comment: Great question!  I've just tried to do this today. Snap

I thought I'd be able to run it through `draft-js-export-html` but it gives me this exception.

`TypeError: this.contentState.getBlocksAsArray is not a function`
`at MarkupGenerator.generate (stateToHTML.js:212)`
`at stateToHTML (stateToHTML.js:579)`

Comment: So weird isn't it.  Using a manual validation function it works fine (using your example code)


`const validation = ({ values }) => {`
`const errors = {};`
`if (!values.draftJSfield.getCurrentContent().hasText()) {`
    `errors.draftJSfield =`
      `'fill in draftJSfield';`
  `}`
    `return errors;`
`};`

Comment: @Buswell I also used manual validation after all. Still... would like to know what's going on here!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with version 0.10.5:

```
value._editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for *Formik#1.5.7* and *yum#0.27.0*

```
Yup.object()
    .test(
        'has text',
        'Cannot save an empty note',
         value => value && value.blocks && value.blocks[0].text.length
    ).required('This field is required.'),
```

And also i had to do some other tricks to trigger touched object and field set of Yum.

```
onChange={(field, value) => {
    setFieldValue(field, value)
}}
onFocus={(field) => {
    setFieldTouched(field)
}}
```

Comment: setting field touched when on focus trick worked for my validation.